# Where to place org-agenda-files sexp

Tags: org-agenda, hooks, org-journal

I have this

```
(setq org-agenda-files (directory-files-recursively "~/Dropbox/org/journal/" "\\.org$"))
```

but I don't know where to place it in order to make sure that on the event of a new daily org-journal file creation in my journal directory (e.g. ~Dropbox/org/journal/2021/02/) the agenda file list will immediately be updated. At the moment I have it placed early in my init.el, which thereafter calls a big, general config.org full of package initializations and tweaks, then a private `custom-set-variables` file. Does this sexp need to be part of some special trigger/hook/event code to know to update the `org-agenda-files` list when a new org-journal day file appears?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: set the variable `org-agenda-files` to be a *list* of all the *directories* that you want to scan recursively for `*.org` files:

```el
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/journal/"))
```

Explanation:

There are two `org-agenda-files` objects: a function and a variable. Org mode calls the *function* when it needs the list. The function looks at the `org-agenda-files` *variable* and proceeds accordingly:

- if the variable is a filename, then it is interpreted as a file that contains the names of all the agenda files. So this is static: you need to add any additional files that you want.
- if the variable is a *list* of filenames, then that's the list of agenda files, except that if an entry in the list is a directory it is scanned recursively for any files that match `org-agenda-file-regexp`. The latter matches files of the form `foo.org` so you don't have to do this yourself.

If you look at the implementation of the *function* `org-agenda-files`, you'll see that it does already the recursive scan, so you don't have to. And it uses the `org-agenda-file-regexp` so you don't have to.

Untested.